# Trouble with Intel HAXM & AVD on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

I have Intel HAXM installed from the SDK, 
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine

I have found the exe but I need to "enable Vt-x" what the hell is that!!
I need this resolved as I have a project that I need to run any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Read about how to open the bios on your particular computer type.  In the setting in there will be VT-X on/off.   Change it to on.